# How to code a reminder popup in Windows 7

Tags: windows, popupwindow

I want a code which would open a popup in Windows 7 at a specific time. I don't want to use Task Scheduler as I would have to manually create the task at the computer of every user for whom I would want this functionality. What I would like to do instead is place a file with the code in the startup folder or on the desktop and it would run automatically in the background, when the time comes it would simply show me a reminder that I need to do job x.

Comment: First, you wouldn't have to set up Task Scheduler manually. Task Scheduler has an API. Second, what problem are you having in implementing what you've described?

Comment: I don't know much about the Task scheduler API, mind sharing some links? Also Rob, my main motive was to have a standalone file that need not be installed on individual system, rather they would work like a macro or a batch file, something which would run in the background.

Comment: You can ask Google about *task scheduler api* just as well as I can; look for URLs at msdn.microsoft.com. You can make a standalone program that installs a scheduled task and then exits. Task Scheduler is already running in the background, so there's no need for another dedicated program to do the same thing. Schedule the task to run your program (with a command-line option to indicate that it should "do job x" rather than schedule a task).